# how to get fundamental cycles and cutsets for the MST problem- igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I was wondering if someone is familiar with a method/function provided by `igraph` to obtain either [the fundamental cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963054/what-is-a-fundamental-cycle-of-a-graph/963628) for an edge not included in the minimum spanning tree (MST) or the fundamental cutset for an edge contained by the MST.

For example, suppose I have a network as shown below, where I color the edges used in the MST.

```
A = matrix(c(
  0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 10,
  8, 0, 3, 6, 9, 10,
  0, 3, 0, 3, 9, 0,
  5, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0,
  10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow= 6 , ncol= 6  ,byrow = TRUE)  


g  <- graph.adjacency(A,weighted=TRUE, mode = c("undirected"))
```

[image]

For this graph, the fundamental cycle of edge `1-6` is represented by `(1-4), (4-3), (3-2), (2-6), (6-1)`.

The fundamental cutset of edge `1-4` is `(1-4), (1-2), (1-6)`.

Comment: Your example is incomplete:  it doesn't show how you obtained that figure.  I think it also has typos (I think the package name is "igraph", and I don't see a 3-6 edge in the graph...).  It might help if you linked to definitions of the terms you use.

Comment: 3-6 was a typo and I fixed it. As for the figure, it has nothing to do with my question. I provided the figure to help people to visualize the adjacency matrix. What I mean is that plotting the figure does not help to identify the fundamental cycles or cutest via a function.

Comment: Check out https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggm/versions/2.5/topics/fundCycles

Comment: @G.Grothendieck:  When I just tried it, `ggm::fundCycles()` errored out.  Any hints?

Comment: The example in the help file works for me.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Would you mind sharing a small example showing how one can use an igraph object in ````fundCycles()```` method, please?

Comment: fundCycles gives you a basis of fundamental cycles. If you want a specific fundamental cycle corresponding to an mst m and an edge e not in m then using g from the question, m <- mst(g) as the mst and edge e = 1:2 (not in m) then `findPath(as_adj(m), st = e[1], en = e[2])` is the fundamental cycle corresponding to m and e.

Comment: Support for computing fundamental cycles is coming in a future version of igraph. Expect it not in the next release, but the one after.